How do I change the list template in a navigation list entry?
How do I change the list template in a navigation list entry?  I created a new template in my app and want to change the list entry to use that template.
From the "Application 125Shared ComponentsListsList DetailsCreate / Edit" screen

In the list region, click the "attributes" tab and select "List Template"

